# Making use of a generated entity's class constructor when using Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, entity-framework-5

I'm using Database First, and for every update to my schema I update the EDMX file and it generates new classes for my model. Unfortunately it doesn't generate the default column values that I specified in the database though (columns such as 'TimeStamp' having 'getdate()' as the default).

Here's how a generated `Student.cs` class looks:

```
namespace ABC.Data
{
    using System;

    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {

        }

        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can make the constructor always set `TimeStamp` to the current date? I've tried creating a helper partial class in the same namespace with the same name etc. but it's not working. Maybe I'm doing the helper class wrong. Ideally I want the helper class to remain the same even after generating new model classes.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood. `TimeStamp = DateTime.Now` in the constructor doesn't work?

Comment: It does, but it's a generated class which I don't want to make changes to. I regenerate my model a lot.

Comment: EntityFramework is using a T4 template to generate the code. Luckily you can replace this template with an own (or modify the existing one) to extend it to your needs. Here you could modify the generated constructor for types. We used this once to extend classes by matching interfaces automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext` class has an event called `ObjectMaterialized` which you can hook up to ...

```
context.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized
```

This event handler can apply the default value.

```
private void ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized(
    object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Entity is Student)
        (e.Entity as Student).TimeStamp = <default value>;
}
```

You'll need to remember to use `context.Set<Student>().Create()` when you need a new instance of `Student` instead of newing up an instance.